# Alternate coloring of DataGridView rows with criterea, and while keeping colored cells the same

Tags: c#, linq, datagridview, foreach, casting

I did have a question, but I solved it while I was entering the question. I hope nobody mind me still posting it here, because I think I might be helpful to others because I couldn't find this exactly like this on stackoverflow. This is my first post, so let me know if I shouldn't be doing that ;)

I'm coloring rows in a DataGridView by sample. But I have certain cells already colored, and I want to keep that coloring.

```
    var sampleRows = dgvData.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
        .Where(x=>x.Cells["Sample"].Value.ToString().Substring(0,4) == "SAMP");

    string lastSample = "";
    Color backColor = Color.LightGray;
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in sampleRows) {
        string currentSample = row.Cells["Sample"].Value.ToString().Substring(0,15);
        if (currentSample != lastSample)
        {
            backColor = (backColor == Color.LightGray) ? Color.DarkGray : Color.LightGray;
            lastSample = currentSample;
        } 
        row.Cells.Cast<DataGridViewCell>()
            .Where(x => x.Style.BackColor == default(Color))
            .ToList().ForEach(x => x.Style.BackColor = backColor);
    }
```

Feedback is still appreciated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a question

Comment: Glad you got it working. Off-topic.

Comment: Thanks, will do that next time.